# Installation of Leiningen 2.X in Mac OS X

Tags: clojure, installation, leiningen

I'm using leiningen ver 1.X, and I'm trying to update it to ver 2.X.

As is written in [this site](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/), I downloaded the script as "lein2", but when I tried to run the "lein2" command, I get this error message.

```
Could not find artifact lein-newnew:lein-newnew:pom:0.3.4 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Could not transfer artifact lein-newnew:lein-newnew:pom:0.3.4 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /Users/smcho/.m2/repository/lein-newnew/lein-newnew/0.3.4
Exception in thread "main" org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies for [#<Dependency lein-newnew:lein-newnew:jar:0.3.4 (compile)>]
    at ...
    ... 4 more
```

It seems that the server doesn't respond, but I'm not sure. What might be wrong? I use Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: what's the rest of the error message? It's not unusual for Lein to look in several repos.

Comment: Do you have mirrors configured in your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`? If so they can interfere.  One way to test this is to temporarily move this file somewhere else and try `lein2 self-install` again.

Comment: @georgek: I added rest of the error message.

Comment: @ivant: I don't have $HOME/.m2/settings.xml.

Comment: What do you think could be the cause of this: Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Specified destination directory cannot be created: /Users/smcho/.m2/repository/lein-newnew/lein-newnew/0.3.4

Comment: Lein2 doesn't use settings.xml afaik.

Comment: @georgek Don't know about lein2, but I'm sure lein1 is influenced by settings.xml

Comment: I don't have experience with OS X, but I guess the problem could be either permissions, or insufficient space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.m2/repository`and `~/.m2/repository/org` directories are root owned so that I couldn't get an access to create subdirectories beneath it. After changing the ownership, everything works fine. I guess I used root privilege when I excited 1.X version of leiningen.

Answer (score 1):

brew has a formula for leiningen.

```
> brew update
> brew install leiningen
> lein -v
Leiningen 2.5.3 on Java 1.8.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```