# Leiningen: Install issues on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, clojure, installation, leiningen

UPDATE:

I have installed via 'homebrew' and updated (see comments to this question), so my ultimate problem is solved, but the particular question I posted here is still open, but I am not really caring since the 'homebrew' solution circumvented it for me.  Thanks to  Diego Basch for his suggestion.

---

I'm trying to install leinigen, following the instructions for a shell script here: http://leiningen.org/ .  I downloaded the `lein' script and executed but got the following error:

```
[/usr/local/bin (git:master) ] $ ./lein.sh 
Could not find artifact lein-newnew:lein-newnew:jar:0.3.7
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
Could not resolve dependencies
```

Closest answer I found on stackexchange was: [Installation of Leiningen 2.X in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553813/installation-of-leiningen-2-x-in-mac-os-x)

but that didn't help.  Any help is appreciated in resolving this.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Why don't you install it via Homebrew?

Comment: OK -- I tried that originally, and it failed.  Upon reflection, I misspelled 'leiningen' as 'leinigen'.  It worked now.  I'll call this solved for my needs.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: fyi, that installed v1.7.1 for me, now I have to follow upgrade examples at: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Upgrading

Comment: Side question: why is your /usr/local/bin a git repository?

Comment: @ Michiel Borkent : It isn't -- I have some mods to my '.bashrc' script that help me when I am in my git repos, but it doesn't behave completely properly, and it is making it look like /usr/local/bin is a git repo, but it isn't.  I'm living with it for now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install Leiningen 2 (that's what you want nowadays) on OSX via Homebrew:

```
brew install leiningen --devel
```

Mind the `--devel` switch, else you get Leiningen 1.7, the latest stable version. More useful information on how to get started can be found on this blog: http://jrheard.tumblr.com/post/40024238467/getting-started-with-clojure

Comment: Thanks!  I did the install (before I saw your post) without the '--devel' switch and did get v1.7.1, and then followed the upgrade in a separate step (see comments to original post).  Thanks again!

Comment: OK, actually, had some issues, started from scratch, installed using your method here, and it now works fine.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in leiningen-RC1 and already fixed for leiningen-RC2.

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/915

Answer (score -1):

for mac os yosemite works just with

```
brew install leiningen
```